I can't get pip on my python3 venv on Ubuntu 24.04
I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04. I added pip with the usual sudo apt install python3-pip, and went to install some packages, but got the error: externally-managed-environment. This was all quite new to me, so I did some reading about venv. Using PyCharm, I attached a virtual environment to my Python project at /home/colin/Dropbox/codebase/Python. All seems to be going well so far. I opened up a terminal and ran:
source /home/colin/Dropbox/codebase/Python/venv/bin/activate

and now I'm in the virtual environment. Next I try to install a package with either:
pip install requests
python3 -m pip install requests

In both cases I get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'. Okay, fair enough, my previous install of pip was for the system, and isn't visible in the virtual environment. So I try to install pip while in the venv:
sudo apt install python3-pip

and get:
python3-pip is already the newest version (24.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.

Huh. Okay. I'm still in the venv, and try:
which pip

and it returns:
/home/colin/Dropbox/Codebase/Python/venv/bin/pip

So what am I doing wrong here? Why can't I install packages with pip in my venv? It might be worth adding that I was following instructions from here for all this, but it doesn't mention this issue.

As I see Dropbox in the path: Synced venvs are often problematic, especially if used on multiple machines.

@KlausD. Yeah, kind of obvious now that you've pointed it out to me. Thanks for being nice about it :-) I deleted the venv inside Dropbox, and re-created one in my home directory, and I'm not having any problems now. Having said that, I actually re-created the new one in the terminal, rather than doing it in PyCharm, so it is possible the problem was also something do with letting PyCharm create the venv.

I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing those could come because this looks more like a sysadmin question rather than a programming question.

If you used PyCharm to create the venv, you should use it to manage the venv (install packages there). By default, venvs get a separate copy of Pip installed automatically, but that doesn't seem to have happened here.

"So I try to install pip while in the venv:" - using sudo escapes the venv, because you are never actually "in" a venv. It just sets some environment variables, and the root user has its own environment variables.

"and it returns: /home/colin/Dropbox/Codebase/Python/venv/bin/pip" - what do you see if you look at that file? It should be a wrapper Python script using an absolute path to the venv's Python. If the wrapper is fine, then the problem is that the venv is missing the actual Pip library despite containing the executable. That would probably be Dropbox's fault, yes.

@KarlKnechtel Extremely informative comments, thank you. In particular your second comment that clarified what it means to be "in" a venv was very helpful for my understanding. Regarding your third comment,  I'm afraid I can no longer check the pip file you mention since it has been deleted.

As a commenter suggested, I've deleted the venv and created a new one outside Dropbox. However, I also did this at the terminal, rather than using PyCharm to create the venv. So I've actually changed two things. One of the two has done the trick, as I'm not having any problems now.

PyCharm just creates the venv using the equivalent of python -m venv. For the record, I generally keep venvs in an entirely separate hierarchy, not in the project directories. Easier to clean up and maintain, too...

@AKX This makes a lot of sense to me and I'll do it myself going forward. Thanks for the suggestion.
